# Remove @Override annotation error in Java8

Tags: java, compiler-errors, annotations, javacompiler, java-annotations

I created the following interface with a single method:

```
public interface Greeting {

   public void perform();
}
```

I was trying to pass an instance of the interface to the greet() method.

```
public class Greeter {

  public void greet(Greeting greeting){
    greeting.perform();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {       
    Greeter greeter=new Greeter();
 }
}
```

I created an implementation of Greeting Interface:

```
public class HelloWorldGreeting implements Greeting {

 @Override
 public void perform() {
    System.out.println("Hello World");

 }
}
```

I was getting the error(The method perform() of type HelloWorldGreeting must override or implement a supertype method) with a quick fix as "Remove @Override annotation"

I also checked compiler configuration. It's 1.8 only.

[image]

Please let me know why is the error coming or help me fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @AaronN.Brock Please let me know why is the error coming or help me fix it?

Comment: Is that the only error?

Comment: @JoeC Are you using the Java 1.8?

Comment: @shmosel yes please

Comment: I am indeed. using 1.8

Comment: Does it go away if you select "Source > Override/Implement Methods..." option?  Nevermind, I remember this error.  Check your build path JRE selection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Please let me know why is the error coming or help me fix it?

**This can happen when the latest class files are not being generated** i.e., the override method signature is not matching because the class files are still referring to old. So, ensure that the project is built properly and the latest class files are being generated.

In eclipse, **Project (at the top bar) -> clean** and check whether the latest class files are being generated (in the `project/target/classes` folder or any other which you have configured). Also, ensure that there are no other errors in the project which might prevent the class files generation. You can also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632632/the-project-cannot-be-built-until-the-build-path-errors-are-resolved) on why project can't be built.

Comment: I used Project>validate option. The error was resolved. Thank you.

Comment: great, yes, the workspace errors makes the project build to fail (i.e., will not generate the .class files using the latest source)

Comment: In my case, updated pom with properties of my version (8), updated buildPath accordingly, and did a maven update project.  this cleared the error.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like your IDE Eclipse is having a JRE system library prior to 1.6 configured in its Java Build Path. And to rectify this you need to configure your Workspace default JRE (JDK1.8.0_xx)'s system library instead of the 1.5 one. To do this you should goto your

project> Build Path> Configure Build Path> Java Build Path > Libraries tab

Here, verify the JRE system library. Most probably this will be 1.5 because which this error is occurring.
Now, click on Add Library
Select Library type -> JRE System Library -> Next

Select Workspace default JRE (jdk 1.8.0_xx) assuming that you have installed this. Otherwise select other installed jre on your system.
Click Finish.
[image]
Your JRE 1.8 should be added to JRE system library.
Now remove JRE 1.5 from the build path and click Apply.
Check your Java Compiler JDK compliance level is still 1.8 and then do a clean build. This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have the "use compliance from the execution environment on Java Build Path" checkbox checked.  You need to make certain you have selected a 1.8 JRE in your Build Path definition.   1.5 JRE will produce this error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem, tried all the solutions mentioned here but nothing worked out to me. So finally I resolved this error by changing the `JRE System Library` option to `Alternate JRE` pointed to `jdk1.8.x_x`.

Thanks!

[image: version error]

Answer (score 0):

> right click on the project -> validate

Then select the file want to `validate`.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

select that file where you are having error, rightclick on it go to validate

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error using Eclipse (simple Swing project, no Maven involved), or just noticed it. It seems the program I was working on runs despite the **@Override** not being recognized, so this could have gone unnoticed.

In any event, validation and project cleaning did not help, nor did updating Eclipse. What finally made the error go away was setting the compiler compliance level to match the JDK in use. I had the project set to a compliance level of 17, but had a while back updated my JDK to 18. When I set the compliance level to 18, the error went away.

I don't really understand why this helped or what exactly the problem is here. AFAIK, a more advanced Java JDK should be able to compile code to match previous versions, yes?