# Error : Could not find or load main class JavaFundamentals.GUIOutput

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

The error text is:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class JavaFundamentals.GUIOutput
```

Console:
[image: Error Picture]

Problems tab:
[image: Problem tab]

Please assist with this error code that comes up and doesn't allow anything to run.

Comment: Aside from `Console` tab there is also `Problems` tab. Take a look at what is listed there.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the **text** of the error message. I can't even read what it is in the screen capture. Also post your code as **text**.

Comment: Possibly related: [The project cannot be built until the build path errors are resolved.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3632632)? In short try using Project > Clean... from the menu. See also other answers if that didn't help.

Comment: Also this may be related: [Missing required library in eclipse for non-required library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12620184)

Comment: In the screen capture of the _Problems_ tab, the following appears: _Project ... is missing a required library_ It's hard for me to help you if I don't know what library is missing. You can change the size of the columns in the table by placing the mouse on the line separating the columns and dragging the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that your application is not compiled, or even if it's compiled java doesn't start it. Make sure to build the application before launch, or try exporting it to jar file, then look at the jar file if it has the classes.